# Why doesn't this update of an axios interceptor work?

Tags: reactjs, axios, interceptor

I have an `axios` client, defined in a provider context and accessed throughout my app with a `useAxios` hook.

The provider uses an access token, which gets updated every few minutes using a token refresh. This is definitely updating correctly.

I use an interceptor to add the token to the request headers. But of course, I want the latest token. So, each time the token updates, I change the interceptor to use the new one. I do this in a useEffect which only fires if the token changes, and I have verified that this effect is firing correctly.

But, any use of the axios client subsequent to a token refresh still uses the original interceptors - the ones that were defined when the app was first loaded. Consequently, after the original token times out, all my requests are unauthenticated **even though I've added an interceptor with an up to date token**, because teh original interceptor is being used...

**THE QUESTION**

How do I correctly update this interceptor so the latest one is used on every query?

**THE CODE**

```js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import { useAuth } from './useAuth'
import { apiErrors } from 'errors'

export const AxiosContext = React.createContext(undefined)

const AxiosProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const { accessToken } = useAuth()

  const axiosClient = React.useMemo(() => {
    return axios.create({
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    })
  }, [])

  // Attach request interceptor to add the auth headers
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(
      'VERIFIED TO WORK - THIS SHOWS PERIODICALLY ON TOKEN UPDATE, WITH THE NEW TOKEN',
      accessToken
    )
    axiosClient.interceptors.request.use((request) => {
      if (accessToken) {
        request.headers.Authorization = `JWT ${accessToken}`
      }
      return request
    })
  }, [axiosClient, accessToken])

  return (
    <AxiosContext.Provider value={axiosClient}>
      {children}
    </AxiosContext.Provider>
  )
}

// A hook for accessing this authenticated axios instance
function useAxios() {
  return React.useContext(AxiosContext)
}

export { AxiosProvider, useAxios }
```

Comment: I am having a similar issue. I think you need to re-create the instance and store it with useMemo, which depends on your token.